# 403 error on some resources when accessing site using https

Tags: iis

I have website when accessing it using http, it works perfectly but when i try to access it using https i got error 403 on some resources mainly(images / js )

http://avangardtech.net

https://avangardtech.net

I've mailed the hosting company for this issue and they did not solved it.

i'm using mvc core 3.1 / shared hosting

attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Is there a detailed error message? You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: it's a shared hosting, i don't think they can do that

Comment: I see that both URL above working fine. Which is not working?

Comment: https://avangardtech.net

if you open the developer tool / network you can see that some files are not being loaded and gives 403 error

Comment: Can https work normally in VS?